# How the UnsupportedOperationException would be thrown?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to read the springboot source code, and I met this in the `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.SpringConfigurationPropertySource` class:

```
private static boolean isFullEnumerable(PropertySource<?> source) {
    PropertySource<?> rootSource = getRootSource(source);
    if (rootSource.getSource() instanceof Map) {
        // Check we're not security restricted
        try {
            ((Map<?, ?>) rootSource.getSource()).size();
        }
        catch (UnsupportedOperationException ex) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return (source instanceof EnumerablePropertySource);
}
```

I'm curious that how the `UnsupportedOperationException` would be thrown? The `Map.size()` method doesn't declare any exceptions. Maybe in the type-casting situation?

Comment: Maybe the `getSource()` method? But `UnsupportedOperationException` isn't a checked exception.

Comment: I've got $5 riding on "we had this weird bug come up once and this was our bandaid". Someone probably had a `Map` with an unimplemented `#size` (strange to begin with).

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` is a runtime exception (so no need to declare it). And `Map` is an interface.... (and any implementation *could* throw this (type of) exception) ..the question is: for which it makes sense?

Comment: The class `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.source.SpringConfigurationPropertySource` is used to present a '_ConfigurationPropertySource backed by a non-enumerable Spring PropertySource or a restricted EnumerablePropertySource implementation (such as a security restricted systemEnvironment source)_'. This `isFullEnumerable` method is responsible for veryfing whther the specified `PropertySource`, which is returned by the `getSource()` method, is full enumerable or restructed enumerable. So I think here the `getSource()` method must be fine. @user207421

Comment: @Rogue: LOL, yes that makes sense! :))

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` == someone forgot or *omitted* to implement an interface method! ;)

Comment: @Rogue  @xerx593  Thank you all. I got this with your comments. It is only used to check whether the `Map#size()` method is implemented or not.